# Store the previous position when i drag the cursor on the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to store the previous position while moving the cursor. I want increase the background-position of the the text if the current position is greater than the previous position, and vise versa.

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".text")
let wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
let posX = 0;
const SPEED = 4;
let previousPos = 0;

text.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  let currentPos = getComputedStyle(text).backgroundPositionX;
  if (currentPos > previousPos) {
    posX += SPEED;
  } else {
    posX -= SPEED;
  }

  previousPos = currentPos;
  console.log(`${previousPos} : ${currentPos}`)
  text.style.backgroundPositionX = `${posX}%`;
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient( to right, rgb(138, 43, 226) 20%, rgb(74, 30, 158) 40%, rgb(74, 30, 158) 60%, rgb(74, 30, 158) 80%, rgb(148, 226, 43) 100%);
  background-size: 400%;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 655px) {
  body {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 502px) {
  body {
    font-size: 6px;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3em 3em;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
}

.text {
  font-size: 6em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgb(138, 43, 226);
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgb(138, 43, 226) 20%, rgb(74, 30, 158) 40%, rgb(74, 30, 158) 60%, rgb(74, 30, 158) 80%, rgb(148, 226, 43) 100%);
  background-size: 200%;
  background-position-x: 0%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="text">Typography</h1>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: You are not checking the actual cursor position anywhere in there, all you do is check the current backgroundPositionX value.

Comment: Protip: Element selectors (`text` and `wrapper`) can usually be constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mousemove` event give you in the parameter `e` the x and y positions of the cursor.

```js
text.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    // e.x -> current x position
    // e.y -> current y position
})
```

With this data you can manage for save the previous position of the cursor.